# Error al instalar en Red Hat

Tags: linux

Al realizar cualquier instalación o actualización en un servidor Red Hat, estoy obteniendo este error:

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
There was an error communicating with RHN.
Red Hat Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.

Error Message:
        Please run rhn_register as root on this client
Error Class Code: 9
Error Class Info: Invalid System Credentials.
Explanation:
     An error has occurred while processing your request. If this problem
     persists please enter a bug report at bugzilla.redhat.com.
     If you choose to submit the bug report, please be sure to include
     details of what you were trying to do when this error occurred and
     details on how to reproduce this problem.

http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/dag/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-2, 'Name or service not known')>
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: dag. Please verify its path and try again
```

Comment: Pregunta tonta: ¿Has hecho ya lo que te indica? ¿Eso genera más errores?

Comment: No funciona. Empieza a pedir confirmación de un repositorio (https://xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com/XMLRPC), y un certificado SSL (/usr/share/rhn/RHNS-CA-CERT). Luego pide usuario y contraseña y a pesar de ingresarlo, sale un error que dice: Invalid username and password combination.

Comment: Creé un nuevo usuario en redhat, y después de ejecutar rhn_register con esas nuevas credenciales, el error es: Problem registering system: Error communicating with server. The message was: Error Class Code: 6000 Error Class Info: RHN is in the process of being decommissioned and systems are no longer able to register.

Comment: MMM, parece que no sale casi información de ese error en internet. En cuanto a lo de Invalid username and password combination, tal vez pasa que hay ciertas condiciones mínimas que debe cumplir las contraseñas como longitud y contener alguna mayúscula o carácter especial.

Comment: No pues he sido muy cuidadoso con ingresar los criterios que se deben cumplir, tanto así que en el proceso de rhn_register ha validado y se diferencia cuando hay alguna combinación errónea. El problema se convierte en algo más de fondo relacionado con el Red Hat.

Comment: Otra pregunta tonta, has probado que se llega a la url? ejecuta un wget url_que_dicequefalla